# Create a list of nested dictionaries from a single csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested-lists, dictionary-comprehension

I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
team,tournament,player
Team 1,spring tournament,Rebbecca Cardone
Team 1,spring tournament,Salina Youngblood
Team 1,spring tournament,Catarina Corbell
Team 1,summer tournament,Cara Mejias
Team 1,summer tournament,Catarina Corbell
...
Team 10, spring tournament,Jessi Ravelo
```

I want to create a nested dictionary (team, tournament) with a list of player dictionary. The desired outcome would be something like:

```
{'data': 
   {Team 1:
       {'spring tournament': 
               {'players': [
                   {name: Rebecca Cardone}, 
                   {name: Salina Youngblood},
                   {name: Catarina Corbell}]
        },
        {'summer tournament': 
               {'players': [
                   {name: Cara Mejias}, 
                   {name: Catarina Corbell}]
               }
        }

   },
    ...
  {Team 10:
       {'spring tournament': 
               {'players': [
                   {name: Jessi Ravelo}]
                }
       }
   }
}
```

I've been struggling to format it like this. I have been able to successfully nest the first level (team # --> tournament) but I cannot get the second level to nest. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
d = {}
header = True
with open("input.csv") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if header:
            header = False
            continue
        team, tournament, player = line.strip().split(",")
        d_team = d.get(team,{})
        d_tournament = d_team.get(tournament, {})
        d_player = d_tournament.get('player',['name'])
        d_player.append(player)
        d_tournament['player'] = d_tournament
        d_team[tournament] = d_tournament
        d[team] = d_team
print(d)
```

What would be the next step in fixing my code so I can create the nested dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your implementation:

- You do `d_player = d_tournament.get('player',['name'])`. But you actually want to get the key named player**s**, and this should be a list of dictionaries. Each of these dictionaries must have the form `{"name": "Player's Name"}`. So you want
  `l_player = d_tournament.get('players',[])` (default to an empty list), and then do `l_player.append({"name": player})` (I renamed it to `l_player` because it's a list, not a dict).
- You do `d_tournament['player'] = d_tournament`. I suspect you meant `d_tournament['player'] = d_player`
- Strip the whitespace off the elements in the rows. Do `team, tournament, player = (word.strip() for word in line.split(","))`

Your code works fine after you make these changes

---

I strongly suggest you use the `csv.reader` class to read your CSV file instead of manually splitting the line by commas.

Also, since python's containers (lists and dictionaries) hold references to their contents, you can just add the container once and then modify it using `mydict["key"] = value` or `mylist.append()`, and these changes will be reflected in parent containers too. Because of this behavior, you don't need to repeatedly assign these things in the loop like you do with `d_team[tournament] = d_tournament`

```
allteams = dict()
hasHeader = True
with open("input.csv") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    if hasHeader: next(csvreader) # Consume one line if a header exists

    # Iterate over the rows, and unpack each row into three variables
    for team_name, tournament_name, player_name in csvreader:
        # If the team hasn't been processed yet, create a new dict for it
        if team_name not in allteams:
            allteams[team_name] = dict()

        # Get the dict object that holds this team's information
        team = allteams[team_name]

        # If the tournament hasn't been processed already for this team, create a new dict for it in the team's dict
        if tournament_name not in team:
            team[tournament_name] = {"players": []}

        # Get the tournament dict object
        tournament = team[tournament_name]

        # Add this player's information to the tournament dict's "player" list
        tournament["players"].append({"name": player_name})

# Add all teams' data to the "data" key in our result dict
result = {"data": allteams}
print(result)
```

Which gives us what we want (prettified output):

```
{
    'data': {
        'Team 1': {
            'spring tournament': {
                'players': [
                    { 'name': 'Rebbecca Cardone' },
                    { 'name': 'Salina Youngblood' },
                    { 'name': 'Catarina Corbell' }
                ]
            },
            'summer tournament': {
                'players': [
                    { 'name': 'Cara Mejias' },
                    { 'name': 'Catarina Corbell' }
                ]
            }
        },
        'Team 10': {
            ' spring tournament': {
                'players': [
                    { 'name': 'Jessi Ravelo' }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to implement your changes and it worked. I'm going to read-up on csv.reader! You're answer does a great job explaining why the code changes were necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The example dictionary you describe is not possible (if you want multiple dictionaries under the key "Team 1", put them in a list), but this snippet:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    your_dict = {}
    with open("yourfile.csv") as file:
        all_lines = file.readlines()

    data_lines = all_lines[1:]  #  Skipping "team,tournament,player" line

    for line in data_lines:
        line = line.strip()  # Remove \n
        team, tournament_type, player_name = line.split(",")
        team_dict = your_dict.get(team, {})  # e.g. "Team 1"

        tournaments_of_team_dict = team_dict.get(tournament_type, {'players': []})  # e.g. "spring_tournament"

        tournaments_of_team_dict["players"].append({'name': player_name})

        team_dict[tournament_type] = tournaments_of_team_dict
        your_dict[team] = team_dict

    your_dict = {'data': your_dict}
```

For this example `yourfile.csv`:

```
team,tournament,player
Team 1,spring tournament,Rebbecca Cardone
Team 1,spring tournament,Salina Youngblood
Team 2,spring tournament,Catarina Corbell
Team 1,summer tournament,Cara Mejias
Team 2,summer tournament,Catarina Corbell
```

Gives the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Team 1": {
      "spring tournament": {
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "Rebbecca Cardone"
          },
          {
            "name": "Salina Youngblood"
          }
        ]
      },
      "summer tournament": {
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "Cara Mejias"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Team 2": {
      "spring tournament": {
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "Catarina Corbell"
          }
        ]
      },
      "summer tournament": {
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "Catarina Corbell"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I overlook somethign but couldn't you use:

```
df.groupby(['team','tournament'])['player'].apply(list).reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might approach it this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
from pprint import pprint

d = defaultdict(dict)

with open('f00.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        d[ row['team'] ].setdefault(row['tournament'], []
                                    ).append(row['player'])

pprint(dict(d))
```

Prints:

```
{'Team 1': {'spring tournament': ['Rebbecca Cardone',
                                  'Salina Youngblood',
                                  'Catarina Corbell'],
            'summer tournament': ['Cara Mejias', 'Catarina Corbell']},
 'Team 10': {' spring tournament': ['Jessi Ravelo']}}
```